# load image url from instagram

Tags: php, url, instagram, instar

Currently i want to get image from instagram url. the url is this

`https://www.instagram.com/p/B_zZCRpB895/media/?size=t`

what im doing now is this :

```
$image = file_get_contents("https://www.instagram.com/p/B_zZCRpB895/media/?size=t");
```

i run it into my AWS server, but the result is go to login instagram.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>\n
<html lang="en" class="no-js not-logged-in client-root">\n
    <head>\n
        <meta charset="utf-8">\n
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">\n
\n
        <title>\n
Login • Instagram\n
</title>\n
\n
        \n
        <meta name="robots" content="noimageindex, noarchive">\n
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">\n
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">\n
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">\n
        <meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover">\n
        <link rel="manifest" href="/data/manifest.json">\n
......
```

however, if i run into my local PC. i can display the image code. is there any way to get the image code from the url instagram?

Comment: Do you mean your code works on your local pc or do you mean you can reach the link in your browser on your pc?

Comment: my code works on my local PC. but different from the AWS server

Comment: It is possible that instagram blocks IP addresses from aws servers that does not use there official api. Maybe aws also send some different headers along the request. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php example for in this links show you how to send headers with your request. I also scrape info from instagram without using there api and for me it works fine (I host it on a Dutch server company)

Answer (score 0):

It think it because these links are designed to serve content on instagram site. So if you want to display images on your site you have to use instagram api instead:

Here is [getting started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started) link for instagram api.

You will end most likly using this endpoint: `graph.facebook.com/{image id}` after you have provided a authenication token too.