# instagram request error with google cloud function

Tags: python-requests, google-cloud-functions, web-crawler, instagram

I'm currently building a crawler that would function like oembed. ( preview card)
When I send an URL to a google cloud function(GCF) server,
GCF takes that URL and makes a GET request with it.
So the problem is that, in the case of Instagram post the GCF server gets response 500 error.
No error with twitter, facebook, other sites but only instagram (as I inspected)

I also checked whether it is a Googlebot issue. but I don't think it is.

here's my GCF code (python)

```
    '''
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from ast import literal_eval
    from flask import jsonify
    import requests
    import json
    import certify
    import urllib3

    http = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED', ca_certs=certifi.where())

    def crawler(request):
        req_data = request.data
        temp_dic = literal_eval(req_data.decode('utf-8'))
        url = json.dumps(temp_dic['url'])
        targeturl = url[1:-1] # get the target URL from user request

        html = http.request('GET', targeturl, headers={'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; "
                                                         "+http://www.google.com/bot.html)"})
        ret=html.headers.items().__str__() # to check header

        text = html.data

        soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
        title = soup.find('meta', property='og:title')
        description = soup.find('meta', property='og:description')
        image = soup.find('meta', property='og:image')

        return_data = {}
        return_data['title'] = title['content']
        return_data['content'] = description['content']
        return_json = json.dumps(return_data, ensure_ascii=False)

        return return_json
    '''
```

and below is HTTP get code for checking

```
    '''
    http = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED', ca_certs=certifi.where())


    targeturl = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/CCqr9qTnX0v/?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link'


    html = http.request('GET', targeturl, headers={'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; "
                                                         "+http://www.google.com/bot.html)"})
    text = html.data
    '''
```

questions.

1. Any difference in the structure/content of HTTP request between them?
2. why GCF doesn't get the expected response?

Comment: found a similar question. maybe Instagram banned gcf IP 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62538453/load-image-url-from-instagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62538453/load-image-url-from-instagram)

Comment: also 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62496539/problem-with-getting-instagram-hashtag-json-without-api-into-google-sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62496539/problem-with-getting-instagram-hashtag-json-without-api-into-google-sheets)